# Airbnb - selenium - filter price input box sets value by visual if clicked off

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to do some scraping of airbnb's website for a small project. Using selenium to try to filter results by price I stumbled upon an issue. I select the max price input box by xpath, then give it a little `WebElement.clear()`. however when I try to do a `WebElement.send_keys(price)`, it gets the price from the visual sliding bar or sets it to max price and ignores my input. It's the same action that happens if you clear the field and then click off it. Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Please show us the HTML structure. Past here the part you are focusing and clicking on

Comment: after pressing the filter button `filter_button = browser.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="site-content"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button')`
and clicking `filter_button.click()`
I then get the max price field `max = browser.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="price_filter_max"]')` and clear it `max.clear()`. but when i try to input to the field it automatically fills it, and ignores my max.send_keys(price)
you can see the same interaction by going to airbnb.com and clicking on filter. then clear the max price field and click off it.

Comment: @TalAngel
The problem is that the between the `max.clear()` and `max.send_keys(price)` selenium clicks off the input box causing it to set itself to max price.

Comment: Sorry, but in StackOverFlow we expect to get a link to the site, and also to get a focus on the relevant elements

Comment: @TalAngel the link is [airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com/) and just press the filters tab. I just have trouble setting the max price.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it using Python:

```
filter = driver.find_element(By.Xpath, '//span[contains(text(),"Filters")]')
filter.click
max_price = driver.find_elemnet(By.Css, 'input[id="price_filter_max"]'
max_price.clear()
max_price.click()
max_price.send_keys('100')
show_btn = driver.find_element(By.Xpath, '//a[contains(text(),"Show")]')
show_btn.click()
```

If that's is not working for you, you can mimic a simple keyboard press. Do this after you click the element via Selenium:

```
ActionChains(driver)\
        .send_keys("100")\
        .perform()
```

Comment: The problem still persists. when i do the max_price.click() it has already 'clicked off' and and the field is auto filled to the max price. meaning i cant enter anything. you can see this if you clear the field yourself and then click anywhere else. Ive sort of found a way around it. if i just click the field and then send max.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE) 5 times to delete whats there. then i can send. is there no better way to do this?

Comment: @CatHat Please see my updated answer